# How to do these arrows with tikz?

Tags: tikz-arrows

I have a figure like the image:

[image]

And I want to draw these arrows like this image:

[image]

This is my code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          %Definindo os vertices
          %Vertice da reta da esquerda
          \tkzDefPoint (0,0){A}
          \tkzDefPoint (0,8){B}
          %Vertices U1
          \tkzDefPoint (1,0){C}
          \tkzDefPoint (1,1.5){D}
          %Vertices U2
          \tkzDefPoint (4,6){E}
          \tkzDefPoint (4,8){F}
          %Chao1
          \tkzDefPoint (-1.5,0){G}
          \tkzDefPoint (6,0){H}   
          %Desenhando as retas
          \draw (A) -- (B);
          \draw (C) -- (D);
          \draw (D) -- (E);
          \draw (E) -- (F);
          \draw (G) -- (H);
          \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
```

Comment: You can make your code a little more efficient by combining some of the `\draw` commands:

`\draw (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- (F);`

Comment: One way to get your arrows is to define their endpoints, as you have done with the other lines, and then put in lines tipped with arrows with code like `\draw[-stealth] (P) -- (Q);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not change the style you used to draw the diagram (I see no point in using `tkz-euclide` here), I will just add the arrows you want. The `intersections` library comes in handy to calculate the points of arrow tips. You draw long-enough equally spaced horizontal rays and let the library calculate their intersection points with the zigzag line. Then, you draw the arrows starting from the `AB` line towards the right till the corresponding intersection point.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}  % internally loads tikz 
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>= {Stealth[scale=2.5,inset=0pt,angle'=20]}]
  %Definindo os vertices
  %Vertice da reta da esquerda
  \tkzDefPoint (0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint (0,8){B}
  %Vertices U1
  \tkzDefPoint (1,0){C}
  \tkzDefPoint (1,1.5){D}
  %Vertices U2
  \tkzDefPoint (4,6){E}
  \tkzDefPoint (4,8){F}
  %Chao1
  \tkzDefPoint (-1.5,0){G}
  \tkzDefPoint (6,0){H}   
  %Desenhando as retas
  \draw (A) -- (B) (G) -- (H);
  \draw[name path=zigzag] (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- (F);          
  \foreach \y in {0.5,1.3,...,7.8}{
    \path[name path=ray] (0,\y) -- (9,\y);
    \path[name intersections={of=zigzag and ray,by=p}];
    \draw[->] (0,\y) -- (p);
  }       
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image]