# How to do these lines with a easy way tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows

I have this image:

[image]

How to do these lines (with a red circle) with a ease way?

[image]

My code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      %Definindo os vertices
      %Vertice da reta da esquerda
      \tkzDefPoint (0,0){A}
      \tkzDefPoint (0,8){B}
      %Vertices U1
      \tkzDefPoint (1,0){C}
      \tkzDefPoint (1,1.5){D}
      %Vertices U2
      \tkzDefPoint (4,6){E}
      \tkzDefPoint (4,8){F}
      %Chao1
      \tkzDefPoint (-1.5,0){G}
      \tkzDefPoint (6,0){H}   
      %Desenhando as retas
      \draw (A) -- (B);
      \draw (C) -- (D);
      \draw (D) -- (E);
      \draw (E) -- (F);
      \draw (G) -- (H);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: Use a pattern? Can you make your code compilable? That's more helpful than just a snippet.

Comment: This question is an addendum of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434067/how-to-do-these-arrows-with-tikz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use patterns, as pointed out by @cfr.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{my north east lines}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{%
\pgfqpoint{8pt}{8pt}}{\pgfqpoint{7pt}{7pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{7.1pt}{7.1pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      %Definindo os vertices
      %Vertice da reta da esquerda
      \tkzDefPoint (0,0){A}
      \tkzDefPoint (0,8){B}
      %Vertices U1
      \tkzDefPoint (1,0){C}
      \tkzDefPoint (1,1.5){D}
      %Vertices U2
      \tkzDefPoint (4,6){E}
      \tkzDefPoint (4,8){F}
      %Chao1
      \tkzDefPoint (-1.5,0){G}
      \tkzDefPoint (6,0){H}   
      %Desenhando as retas
      \draw (A) -- (B);
      \draw (C) -- (D);
      \draw (D) -- (E);
      \draw (E) -- (F);
      \draw (G) -- (H);
      \fill [pattern=my north east lines] ([yshift=-0.25cm]G) rectangle (H);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]